# Unknown action hi in contract error while deploying smart contract on testnet

Tags: c++, blockchain, smartcontracts, eos

I am tring to deploy contract on testnet http://api.kylin.alohaeos.com. I have following hello2.cpp program

```
#include <eosiolib/eosio.hpp>
#include <eosiolib/print.hpp>

using namespace eosio;

class suniltestacc : public contract {
  public:
      using contract::contract;

      [[eosio::action]]
      void hi( name user ) {
              //require_auth( user );
              //print( "Hello, ", name{user} );
                print( "Hello, ", user);
      }
};

EOSIO_DISPATCH(suniltestacc, (hi))
```

I compiled this program using `eosio-cpp -o hello2.wasm hello2.cpp --abigen`. It gives me two warnings which I ignored.

```
Warning, empty ricardian clause file
Warning, empty ricardian clause file
```

Then I execute `cleos -u http://api.kylin.alohaeos.com set contract suniltestacc /home/varsha/Varsha/contracts/hello2` 
This runs successfully, after that I am trying this command

```
cleos -u https://api.kylin.alohaeos.com push action suniltestacc hi '["bobmarley"]' -p suniltestacc@active
```

It is giving me error

```
error 2019-01-22T08:10:35.520 thread-0  main.cpp:3449                 main                 ] Failed with error: Assert Exception (10)
!action_type.empty(): Unknown action hi in contract suniltestacc.
```

Can somebody help me with this.

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing wrong with this, Its all working fine.

Below is the result when i called your function.

```
cleos -u https://api.kylin.alohaeos.com push action suniltestacc hi '["bobmarley"]' -p doslnjslongd@active
```

executed transaction: 8faa9669ed143c979afa842489dafdfc610e0c6ad4f2831039a170448f867835  104 bytes  134 us

## suniltestacc <= suniltestacc::hi             {"user":"bobmarley"}

warning: transaction executed locally, but may not be confirmed by the network yet         ]

Let me know if i can help you further.